# What are the specific differences between .msi and setup.exe file?

Tags: windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I searched a lot, but all are guessed answers.  Help me to find the exact answer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902841/why-do-so-many-programs-have-both-a-setup-exe-and-a-setup-msi

Comment: Here is a **[more recent answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/23815524/129130)**

Comment: I wanted to install a program that came with both an EXE and MSI installer.  I first installed from MSI, which only installed the program files (not any prerequisites or dependencies, and didn't create Start Menu icons).  When I manually launched the program, it failed saying certain DLLs were missing.  Installing from the EXE installed other things too, and the product ran just fine.  I would say, if a software maker provides both an EXE and MSI option for installing, use the EXE.

Answer (score 300):

An MSI is a Windows Installer database. Windows Installer (a service installed with Windows) uses this to install software on your system (i.e. copy files, set registry values, etc...).

A setup.exe may either be a bootstrapper or a non-msi installer. A non-msi installer will extract the installation resources from itself and manage their installation directly. A bootstrapper will contain an MSI instead of individual files. In this case, the setup.exe will call Windows Installer to install the MSI.

Some reasons you might want to use a **setup.exe**:

- Windows Installer only allows one MSI to be installing at a time. This means that it is difficult to have an MSI install other MSIs (e.g. dependencies like the .NET framework or C++ runtime). Since a setup.exe is not an MSI, it can be used to install several MSIs in sequence.
- You might want more precise control over how the installation is managed. An MSI has very specific rules about how it manages the installations, including installing, upgrading, and uninstalling. A setup.exe gives complete control over the software configuration process. This should only be done if you **really** need the extra control since it is a lot of work, and it can be tricky to get it right.

Comment: I was going to type this - this is probably what he is looking for

Comment: In my experience building an MSI installer is *a lot of work* compared to building an exe based installer. This greatly depends on the tools your using to build the installer in the first place. Unfortunately all of the MSI based installer tools I've seen have either been commercial GUI tools or complex WiX based tools. Neither of which suits my needs particularly well (i.e. automatically building installers with a script).

Comment: So I am still wondering why MSI exists. What problem was it trying to solve when exe seems to work fine?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan MSI is a framework dedicated to the installation of software only, unlike `.exe` which is simply an executable file. MSI has specifications within it that more effectively handle writing software to your PC.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Installations are tricky to get right. The are a lot of things to consider that someone who has never made an installer might not realize, especially uninstalling, upgrading, repairing, and modifying the installed software. MSI gives a framework to make it easier to have installers that work more reliably and consistently. Users should have a similar experience when installing any software, and that's difficult to do without a framework like MSI providing and enforcing a standard. As long as users are installing software, I think there will be a need for a framework like this.

Answer (score 18):

.msi files are windows installer files without the windows installer runtime, setup.exe can be any executable programm (probably one that installs stuff on your computer)

Answer (score 16):

**MSI** is an installer file which installs your program on the executing system.

**Setup.exe** is an application (executable file) which has msi file(s) as its one of the resources.
Executing Setup.exe will in turn execute msi (the installer) which writes your application to the system.

**Edit (as suggested in comment):** Setup executable files don't necessarily have an MSI resource internally

Comment: Setup executable files don't necessarily have an MSI resource internally.

Answer (score -11):

MSI is basically an installer from Microsoft that is built into windows. It associates components with features and contains installation control information. It is not necessary that this file contains actual user required files i.e the application programs which user expects. MSI can contain another setup.exe inside it which the MSI wraps, which actually contains the user required files.

Hope this clears you doubt.

Comment: This is confusing and generally incorrect - in that `MSI` files usually **DO NOT** wrap `setup.exe` files, but rather vice versa.

Comment: "MSI can contain another setup.exe inside it which the MSI wraps" is incorrect! Rather, the converse is true: a .exe has a .msi inside it.