# Package signing , and digital certificate

Tags: c#, package, .net-assembly, digital-signature, code-signing

I Created a windows forms application using c# the output of the App is .exe , in the references of this project , I had added a reference of many dlls that this project needs all of them are Created by me.But these referenced dlls , some of them are using third parities Dll.

I packed the .exe and all referenced dll in an installer project using wix Toolset.

Note that the .exe and the installer has no strong names and not signed with key.

I upload this .msi result file into an intranet server , but when users download it from intranet it through google chrome , it  gives a warning message like in fig1.[Chrome warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ImL.png)

and when the user Double clicks the .msi file after downloading to start installation process , it activates windows smart screen .[Smart screen warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCYgC.png)

and while running the installer it displays User account control message with yellow banner as in fig3.[windows smart screen warning][3]

I made a lot of invistigations and i had find out that this is because my code is not digitally signed with digital certificate, actually i have no experience on this and i don't know if this is the true reason or what.

And do i need to make my .exe strongly signed by signing the assembly from signing tab of .net , I also have no experience about singing an executable package.

all what i need is that i don't want the user to feel like he is downloading and running something that is not trusted.

if the reason is that the package needs digital certificate , do i have to sgin the assembly with strong name to be able to sign it with digital certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows treats all application which are published by verified publisher as non-trusted application. If you want to make your application trusted by windows digitally sign your application.

1. First buy Code-Signing-Certificate. lets say from  Godaddy cheapest available (https://in.godaddy.com/web-security/code-signing-certificate). After buying certificate just follow procedure on godaddy to get your Certificate(.pfx) file.
2. Install visual studio express
3. Install InstallShield for generating .exe
4. You can sign your output with the certificate by using installshield easily. Refer the screenshot for details.[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast replay and your answer .I just need to ask couple questions. Regarding your point [Install InstallShield for generating .exe] why do i have to installShiled , and what is .exe i should Generate?? i thought i should buy the certificate and then use it to just sign my.msi package using signtool.exe which exists in microsoft SDK. 2 - Can i just create a test certificate using visual studio and use it to sign my .msi file using signtool.exe .3-if i bought the certificate and use it as u suggested to sign my .msi package,how it would be trusted on users machines ??

Comment: You can go ahead with TestCertificate and sign .msi with Signtool.exe .  First generate TestCertificate and install in the machine which you are using to sign .exe or .msi. after that try to run the app you will see publisher name. TestCertificate only works in your machine. If you buy certificate, install that certificate in the machine which you are using to sign .exe or .msi. They try to run in any machine you will see publisher name.

Comment: Installshield is SoftwareTool for creating installers which has features like code signing. It is very easy to sign app using this software(which internally signs using Signtool.exe).             :)

Comment: Look at this for knowing differences between .msi and .exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789530/what-are-the-specific-differences-between-msi-and-setup-exe-file

Comment: Thanks very much :) @null1941