# Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2015

I have built an Installshield installer successfully..and it is up and running..But I am a few customization away from perfection .**While asking for administrative privilages in the course of installation..The permission seeking Dialog box shows weird message**.which is unpleasant to anyone .I am attaching the screenshot below..

[image: weird installshield message]
 As I am new to Installshield Premier edition..can anyone please help me out with this- **how can I change the pointed string** AND ALSO the publisher name from unknown to my name(if possible)?

Comment: I don't know anything about InstallShield but I can answer this: _"how can I change (...) the publisher name from unknown to my name(if possible)?"_ - In order to become a "known" publisher you've got to purchase a digital Code Signing Certificate from a certificate bureau and use that to sign your application and your installer.

Comment: That one u answered was secondary thats why I gave (if possible)  clause..
My main issue is the pointed text

Comment: And it is possible, so I answered it :). -- As I said I don't know anything about InstallShield, but I doubt you can change that first string as the installer copies itself to a temporary location before installing (most installers do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UAC Prompt***: "*If you Authenticode-sign your .msi package, Windows will show that as the name. Otherwise, you get MSI's temporary copy of it, which has a random name.*" ([**from Bob Arnson's  answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865592/129130) (`WiX developer & overall master of conciseness`).

So you need to get a **digital code-signing certificate** - if you don't have one - and then you will get rid of this problem once you sign the MSI package.

Technically you use the `/d` command line argument when executing `signtool.exe` to sign your MSI file ([**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4315846/129130) - Scott Langham). I believe you specify the name you want displayed with this option. [**Also see this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869564/129130).

***Code Signing Certificate & SmartScreen***: Please see this answer for more details on signing, Installshield and the issue of trust and **SmartScreen** / Windows Defender (very important issue): **[How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018/50414337#50414337)**.

A direct link to the **Installshield help file**: [**Digital Signing and Security**](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield28helplib/helplibrary/IHelpReleaseDigitalSignature.htm).

---

***Some Links*** (adding as reference for the community - shouldn't be needed for you):

- [The UAC prompt shows a temporary random Program Name for msi, can the correct name be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315840/the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random-program-name-for-msi-can-the-correct-na)
- [WIX-Installer MSI Publisher Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589754/wix-installer-msi-publisher-unknown)
- [Package signing , and digital certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703176/package-signing-and-digital-certificate)
- [WIX-Installer MSI Publisher Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589754/wix-installer-msi-publisher-unknown/40750622)
- [Odd 'Program name' when installing signed msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863137/odd-program-name-when-installing-signed-msi-installer)
- [Why do I still see publisher unknown with the UAC prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733092/why-do-i-still-see-publisher-unknown-with-the-uac-prompt)
- [How to pass the Windows Defender SmartScreen Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806909/how-to-pass-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-protection)
- [How to avoid the "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-from?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [WiX: Digitally Sign BootStrapper project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381525/wix-digitally-sign-bootstrapper-project/20474917)
- [signtool fail with Inno Setup with exit code 0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863018/signtool-fail-with-inno-setup-with-exit-code-0x1)
- [InnoSetup - fails to use global sign EV code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470660/innosetup-fails-to-use-global-sign-ev-code-signing)
- [Is it possible to define a Windows Installer-uninstaller filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079546/is-it-possible-to-define-a-windows-installer-uninstaller-filename/48080788)