# How to Sign exe or msix Setup that can run on everywhere

Tags: installshield, setup-project, sign, advanced-installer, msix

I want to sign an Exe (msi) or MSIX setup file to run on all systems without any problems (like smart screen).
I used InstallShield and Advanced Installer for creating setup Both of these applications can be signed by the PFX file However, the user must manually install the signature before executing the setup file
So how can I sign a setup file that runs on all systems without any problems and does not require the user to install a signature?

Comment: A couple of answers to check: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209972/129130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for you is to purchase and use a digital signature certificate (of Microsoft Authenticode type) issued by a certificate vendor that is a trusted authority within the default Windows system trusted authorities list. A certificate issued by any of the most known certificate vendors should be enough to fulfill your request.

Once you purchase such a certificate file you can simply configure and use it in "Digital Signatures" section of your Advanced Installer or ISH setup project.