# Windows : What's the difference between a .msi installer and a .exe installer?

Tags: windows

I've been offered this as I tried to install a software (Inkscape; https://inkscape.org/de/herunterladen/windows-installer/) on my Windows 7 machine:

[image]

Now I wonder:

What's the difference between the msi-installer and the exe-installer?

"exe" stands for "executable file"? Isn't every programm an exe-file in Windows OS? So what's the difference?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789530/what-are-the-specific-differences-between-msi-and-setup-exe-file